# Plot3D - Rugged surface at the boundary

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a function over a tirangular region

```
   F[x_, y_] := -(0.1/x)*(Log[(x - y)/0.1])
   Plot3D[F[x, y] , {x, 0.1, 3}, {y, 0, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x > y], 
   PlotRange -> {-2, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> 60]
```

and I get some a jagged surface on one boundary.

[image]

I appreciate the surface is very steep on the $x=y$ line, and it could pose numerical difficulties.

Yet, is there a workaround to obtain a more aesthetically pleasing plot?

Thanks

Comment: can't run your code. F100234 not defined.

Comment: My apologies, should be corrected now, thanks

Comment: I get different plot. V 12. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gm7xN.png)

Comment: Adding `PlotPoints -> 100` might help.

Comment: @Nasser, please consider my further edit, I have checked it now twice, sorry.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks, I have tried, it just makes the "jaggedness" occur at a finer scale

Comment: The trick is to push that to a scale that cannot be seen ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Boole` to the plot argument:

```
Plot3D[F[x, y] Boole[x >= y], {x, 0.1, 3}, {y, 0, 5},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x > y], PlotRange -> {-2, 1},AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> 60]
```

[image]

Comment: works well, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.